# How large is $f_{\Gamma_{0}}(2)$ in the Fast-Growing Hierarchy?

Tags: ordinal-analysis

If my ordinal arithmetic is correct, $f_{\Gamma_{0}}(2)=f_{\epsilon_{\epsilon_0}}(2)$ so $$f_{\epsilon_{\omega}}(2)\ll f_{\Gamma_{0}}(2)\ll f_{\epsilon_{\epsilon_1}}(2),$$ but that doesn't show anything new. Maybe bounds with [Bower's Exploding Array Function](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Bowers%27_Exploding_Array_Function) or [Cascading-E Notation](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Cascading-E_notation) can help.